# Call Camera Service inside fragment, how to handle the callback?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Normally to call the camera we use the code like:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

to start camera services. And use the onActivityResult to get the return photo uri. It works well in the activity. However, for the fragment, the call back is only trigger in Main Activity instead of the fragment, how to setup the callback?

Notice the fragment is inside the tabhost and after transcation so I can not simply `tabhostmanager().findviewbytag()`

Thanks a lot

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("test1", "result2");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Update:

```
The tabost
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"),HomeFragment.class, null);
```

And I use fragment transaction so findviewbyid/ tag return other instance, thanks

Comment: You are going to have to handle the callback in your host activity.

Comment: but all my variable is inside fragment e.g. the imageview that I place the return photo. How to interact with it? thanks

Comment: It is best to have a way to call back to your fragment from the host activity. So in your fragment you need to call **onActivityResult** then inside that call **super.onActivityResult(...)**. This will have the host activity listen for the call back. In your host activity, pass the data that is passed from the call back to your fragment and handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to handle the callback in your activity and then call your fragment with the data coming form the camera application.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ((YourFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layout_id)).yourFragmentMethodToHandleDataFromCamera(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the source code of the FragmentTabHost class in order to find a way to get a reference to your fragment since to its tag.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=40035&aid=400350000000&name=FragmentTabHost.java&token=WHVg3x7dbNNznLcPPSwWxnin_X0%3A1367343846708